# partitioning data by row number in r

Tags: r, data-partitioning

Now I have data

```
dat <- data.frame(y,x1,x2)
```

there are about 200 rows.

And I want to partition this data by row number

like 1 to 150 and 150 to 200

How can I do this?

Comment: `dat[1:150,]` and `dat[150:200,]` ? Read `help('[')`

Comment: Don't you mean `1 to 150` and `151 to 200`?

Comment: Yes that's right thx

Comment: You can `split` the dataset in to two in a `list` by `split(dat, as.numeric(gl(nrow(dat), 150, nrow(dat)))`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @etienne use `[`

```
dat <- data.frame("y" = 1:200 , "x1" = rnorm(200), "x2" = rnorm(200)) 

dat1 <- dat[1:150,]
dat2 <- dat[151:200,]
```